# Asp .Net Core RC2 on Windows IoT and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to create an Asp.Net Core RC2 site running on a Raspberry Pi 3 using Windows IoT.

I found the following tutorial:
https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4

But this is for RC1. So is there already a tutorial for RC2, did anybody do so already?

And the Second question is, can you debug an asp.net core site on Windows IoT?

Thanks for your help.

Greetings
Markus

Answer (score 5):

As far I know, it's not supported yet.

Like @davidfowl said:

> This isn't on the roadmap for 1.0 as for future plans I can't say for sure when.

Please follow [RC2 for Windows IoT](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1531) (aspnet/Home #1531) issue on GitHub.

**Update:**

Win10 IoT is mentioned in [ASP.NET Core v1.1.0 Planning #1685](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1685):

> WebListener server (for Service Fabric & public-facing ready self-host without reverse proxy and Windows 10 IoT/UWP support)

However I'm not sure what this mean ?