# Webserver on windows 10 IOT?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

Can I create a webapplication on my windows 10 IOT running device (R-PI 3)?

On other PI's I've got Debian running with LightHttpd, but I can't seem to find anything on a webserver on Win10 IOT device.

I did see some examples on self creating a -very simple- webserver (ie listening on a port) but there should be more than that?

PS
I added 2 tages: Windows IOT and Windows-10-IOT-Core.... are these the same?

Comment: It does have a server available, but it has not yet been exposed for use. That is how they serve up the pages in the Device Portal. I use iotweb-master (https://github.com/sensaura-public/iotweb), and it is working well. One note is that the default behvior requires the resource be embedded, but the code can be modified to do that. The other examples that are out there are trivial, and not suited to heavy lifting.

Answer (score 5):

> Can I create a webapplication on my windows 10 IOT running device
>   (R-PI 3)?

Yes, you can start with [Hello blinky](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Samples/helloblinky) official sample. There are also [Python](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloblinkyserver) and [Node.js supported](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworldnode.htm).

Using ASP.NET, you can [publish Web Application on Windows IoT core](https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4). (Note the version of ASP.NET, more detailed information is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905930/asp-net-core-rc2-on-windows-iot-and-raspberry-pi-3).)

And, [restup](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup) is a HTTP server for universal windows platform (UWP) apps that can run on Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT core.

> PS I added 2 tages: Windows IOT and Windows-10-IOT-Core.... are these
>   the same?

[Windows IoT core](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Explore/IoTCore) is an edition of Windows 10 differs from desktop and mobile editions. It is optimized for smaller devices with limited resources, such as Raspberry Pi 2 and 3.

[Window IoT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/windows-iot) is something about Internet of Things you can create with Windows.

For tags in SO, "Windows IoT core" and "Window IoT" have identical function.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. I'll have a look at the links. On this part "a HTTP server for universal windows platform (UWP) apps": is a http server for UWP apps different than a http server for other apps?

Comment: About the "Windows 10 IoT Core - Publish ASP.NET Web Application" link: I did find that one before, but I thought it should be easier to just deploy a webapplication (like a 'normal' publish).

Comment: About the Python example: does that mean I have to program python? I thought there would be a simple webserver around so I could publish my ASP.NET apps. I also do programming Python on the Raspberry Pi, on the Debian OS, what will I gain by moving to windows10 IOT then?

Comment: @Michel [A Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app can run on any Windows-based device, from your phone to your tablet or PC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro) including Raspberry Pi. It is different from classical desktop and mobile apps that can't run on Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT core.

Comment: @Michel Not only Python, but also C#, C++ and Node.js are supported, you can choose one of them you like. There are [PTVS](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/releases/tag/v2.2.5post1) and [Python UWP SDK](https://github.com/ms-iot/python/releases) help you create Python app with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this that I've come across which might interest you:

1) As you suggest, it is very simple as you suggest to write you're own server app or app service that listens on a port and responds. Here is a decent example which was easy to follow and implement:

https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/04/08/building-a-windows-10-iot-core-background-webserver/

2) Also, it is possible to develop a plugin for Windows Device Portal (WDP) by following the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/october/windows-device-portal-write-a-windows-device-portal-packaged-plug-in

I have tried this and it works very nicely. It demonstrates how to serve static content and dynamic content either from the foreground or a background task.

Comment: I have just discovered that the restup solution proposed by @Rita now on github below may have initially developed from the webserver demo on Sander van develde's site! Small world.